# Tic-Tac-Toe program in about 250 lines

Tags: beginner, c, tic-tac-toe

I'm new to C programming and I recently challenged myself to writing a Tic-Tac-Toe program. I found that my code becomes lengthy very quickly with so many `if` statements. This code works as is (and I still wish to add more features). I just think there's probably a more neat/efficient way to program this. Any ideas on how to trim this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0

int main()
{
    playGame();
    return 0;
}
int playGame()
{

    char scanned[3];
    printf("Do you wish to play tick-tack-toe?\n");
    scanf("%s", scanned);
    if(strcasecmp(scanned,"yes")==0)
        startGame();

    else
    {
        if (strcmp(scanned,"no")==0 || strcmp(scanned,"nah")==0 || strcmp(scanned,"naw")==0)
        {
            printf("That's too bad!/nThis program will now end.");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Not valid input!/nThis program will now end.");
        return 1;
    }
}
int startGame()
{
    //Sets up board for values 1-9;
    char board[3][3] =
    {
        {'1','2','3'},
        {'4','5','6'},
        {'7','8','9'}
    };

    bool winner = false;
    printf("\n\nHere is your playing board. Player One is Os and Player Two is Xs\n");
    printf("Entering a number 1-9 (then pushing enter) as shown below will use\nthe current Player's turn in that location.\n");


    printf("\n\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
    printf("-----------\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
    printf("-----------\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);

    int x=0;
    int j=0;
    int turn[9];
    while (j<sizeof(turn)/sizeof(turn[0]) && winner == false)
    {
        scanf("%d",&turn[j]);
        //turn[j] = x;
        if (j%2==0)
        {
            if (turn[j]==1)
            {
                board[0][0] = 'O';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
            if (turn[j]==2)
            {
                board[0][1] = 'O';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
            if (turn[j]==3)
            {
                board[0][2] = 'O';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
            if (turn[j]==4)
            {
                board[1][0] = 'O';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
            if (turn[j]==5)
            {
                board[1][1] = 'O';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
            if (turn[j]==6)
            {
                board[1][2] = 'O';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
            if (turn[j]==7)
            {
                board[2][0] = 'O';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
            if (turn[j]==8)
            {
                board[2][1] = 'O';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
        }
        if (turn[j]==9)
        {
            board[2][2] = 'O';
            printf("\n\n");
            printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
            printf("-----------\n");
            printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
            printf("-----------\n");
            printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
        }
        if (j%2!=0)
        {
            if (turn[j]==1)
            {
                board[0][0] = 'X';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
            if (turn[j]==2)
            {
                board[0][1] = 'X';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
            if (turn[j]==3)
            {
                board[0][2] = 'X';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
            if (turn[j]==4)
            {
                board[1][0] = 'X';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
            if (turn[j]==5)
            {
                board[1][1] = 'X';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
            if (turn[j]==6)
            {
                board[1][2] = 'X';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
            if (turn[j]==7)
            {
                board[2][0] = 'X';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
            if (turn[j]==8)
            {
                board[2][1] = 'X';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }
            if (turn[j]==9)
            {
                board[2][2] = 'X';
                printf("\n\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
                printf("-----------\n");
                printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
            }




        }


        j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24):

### Boolean values

[C99 has Boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c): `#include <stdbool.h>`.

### Variable names

```
int x=0;
int j=0;
```

`x` and `j` don't describe what they do.  Is `j` the turn number?  Also, I don't see `x` used anyway except this commented out line: `//turn[j] = x;`.

### Repetition

I would set up a variable name to reduce all those `if`s.  Maybe something like:

```
char token = (j % 2 == 0) ? 'O' : 'X';

if (turn[j]==1)
{
    board[0][0] = token;
    printf("\n\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
    printf("-----------\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
    printf("-----------\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
}

// ...
```

Also, nested `for` loops may be useful here to reduce that list of `if`s to one value.

### Edit:

In clarification to the comments, the ?: operator is a ternary conditional operator.  It works as follows:

> ```
> condition ? (run this statement if condition evaluated to true) : (run this statement if condition evaluated to false);
> ```

In this example, I used it in combination with an assignment operation.

---

C99 is informal terminology to mean **ISO/IEC 9899:1999**, which was finalized in 1999.  The latest version of C is C11, which was finalized in 2011, and which should also support Boolean variables.

Comment: I was testing something earlier with an error I was getting, I'll remove x.

Answer (score 21):

From a quick glance, this snippet looks like it could be extracted into its own parameterized function:

```
    printf("\n\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
    printf("-----------\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
    printf("-----------\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
```

DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself ;-)

Comment: Oh and then I can just call the function over and over?

Comment: Exactly that.  Write once, use a bunch.

Comment: this would be a good time to learn about huristics, the min/max algorithm, alpha/beta pruning and certain related topics.

Answer (score 14):

Notes:

- It seems that you don't need to store the input in the `turn` array
- You are not asserting legal user input (values between `1` and `9`)
- You are not asserting that the user inputs a new value at every turn
- Since user input is a single character, you may as well scan for `"%c"`
- You can calculate the indexes to `board` based on the user input (`turn`)
- You can calculate the player (`x` or `o`) based on the iteration number (`j`)
- You are not changing the value of `winner` (initialized as `false`) anywhere

---

Implementation:

```
int  j;
char turn;
int  index;
char players[] = {'o','x'};

for (j=0; j<9; j++)
{
    while (1)
    {
        scanf("%c",&turn);
        if (turn == '\n')
            continue; // skip the newline character
        index = turn-'1';
        if (!(0 <= index && index <= 8))
            printf("Invalid input\n");
        else if (board[index/3][index%3] == players[0] ||
                 board[index/3][index%3] == players[1])
            printf("Already chosen\n");
        else
            break;
    }

    board[index/3][index%3] = players[j%2];

    printf("\n\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
    printf("-----------\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
    printf("-----------\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);

    /*
    if there is a winner
    {
        print the winner
        break;
    }
    */
}
```

---

As you can see, I left it for you to check `if there is a winner`...

Comment: Thankyou, that makes sense. The code isn't fully complete yet, that is why some variables are unused :P

Answer (score 10):

Some big problems in your code others haven't mentioned:

1. You use `strcasecmp`. This function is non-standard. This makes your code non-portable.
2. You use

   ```
   scanf("%s", scanned);
   ```

   and `scanf` will happily scan unlimited characters and write it into `scanned`. You will (and already does) suffer from a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). `scanned` can hold a maximum of 2 characters (+1 for the NUL-terminator). Typing more than two characters leads to [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as other characters are written into an invalid memory location.

   Fix this problem by changing

   ```
   char scanned[3];
   ```

   to

   ```
   char scanned[4]; /*Can hold a max of 3 chars (+1 for the NUL-terminator at the end)
   ```

   and

   ```
   scanf("%s", scanned);
   ```

   to

   ```
   scanf("%3s", scanned); /*Scan a max of 3 chars and append a NUL-terminator at the end*/
   ```

   Do note that you might have to [clear the input buffer to remove extra characters](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html) (if the user inputs more than 3 characters).
3. The function `playGame()` is designed to return an `int`. If the user types in `"yes"` for the `scanf` in `playGame()`, the `if` will execute and the function exits **without a `return` statement**. This leads to [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Fix it by adding `return 0;` at the end of that function.
4. The function `startGame()` is also designed to return an `int`, but you never return an `int` from it. This, again, leads to [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). If you do not want it to return a value change

   ```
   int startGame()
   ```

   to

   ```
   void startGame()
   ```

   which indicates that the function will not return any value.

Other issues:

- You have a lot of repeating code:

  ```
  printf("\n\n");
  printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
  printf("-----------\n");
  printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
  printf("-----------\n");
  printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
  ```

  which can be put into a function named `printBoard()`:

  ```
  void printBoard() {

      printf("\n\n");
      printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
      printf("-----------\n");
      printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
      printf("-----------\n");
      printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
  }
  ```

  The logic used can also be simplified by using loops:

  ```
  void printBoard() {

      printf("\n\n");

      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[i][0], board[i][1], board[i][2]);
          printf("-----------\n");
      }
  }
  ```

  But this also prints the last `printf` an extra time, so use

  ```
  void printBoard() {

      printf("\n\n");

      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[i][0], board[i][1], board[i][2]);
          if(i != 2)
          {
              printf("-----------\n");
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Here:

  ```
  scanf("%d",&turn[j]);
  ```

  You don't check if user enters a valid number. You also store the inputs in an array. Why? So this:

  ```
  int turn[9];
  ```

  can be

  ```
  int turn;
  ```

  Checking the return value of `scanf` will reveal if the user enters a number or something else. If your `scanf` returns 1, it indicates that `scanf` successfully got a number as input and if it returns 0, it indicates that `scanf` failed to scan a number. It can also return `-1`(`EOF`) if it encounters a special value called `EOF`.
- Use meaningful variable names instead of `x`,`scanned` etc. I leave this up to you.
- This:

  ```
  else
  {
      if (strcmp(scanned,"no")==0 || strcmp(scanned,"nah")==0 || strcmp(scanned,"naw")==0)
      {
          printf("That's too bad!/nThis program will now end.");
          return 1;
      }
      printf("Not valid input!/nThis program will now end.");
      return 1;
  }
  ```

  can be written as

  ```
  else
  {
      char* exit_strings[] = {"no", "nah", "naw"};

      for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(exit_strings); i++)
          if (strcmp(scanned, exit_strings[i]) == 0)
          {
              printf("That's too bad!\n");
              printf("This program will now end.\n");
              return 1;
          }
      printf("Not valid input!\n");
      printf("This program will now end.\n");
      return 1;
  }
  ```

  making your code better. Note that you used `/n` while `\n` indicates a newline character.

Comment: You're implementation of `printBoard` with the for-loop is buggy. It should print a line of dashes *between* every other line. Right now it prints that line *after* each other line, which means one extra line is printed.

Comment: @jacwah Yeah. Fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a revised working version of your code.

It includes the usage of boolean variables; deals with code-repetition; implements cases of wrong user inputs; and decides stalemate, winner cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print(char board[][3])
{
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[i][0], board[i][1], board[i][2]);
        if(i!=2)
            printf("-----------\n");
    }
}
bool winnerCheck(char board[][3], char check)
{
    bool winner = board[0][0]==check && board[0][1]==check && board[0][2]==check || board[1][0]==check && board[1][1]==check && board[1][2]==check || board[2][0]==check && board[2][1]==check && board[2][2]==check || board[0][0]==check && board[1][0]==check && board[2][0]==check || board[0][1]==check && board[1][1]==check && board[2][1]==check || board[0][2]==check && board[1][2]==check && board[2][2]==check || board[0][0]==check && board[1][1]==check && board[2][2]==check || board[0][2]==check && board[1][1]==check && board[2][0]==check;
    if (winner)
        printf("Player %d wins!\n", (check=='O')?1:2);
    return winner;
}
void startGame()
{
    //Sets up board for values 1-9;
    char board[3][3] =  {   {'1','2','3'},
                            {'4','5','6'},
                            {'7','8','9'}
                        };
    bool winner = false;
    printf("\nHere is your playing board. Player One is Os and Player Two is Xs\n");
    printf("Entering a number 1-9 (then pushing enter) as shown below will use\nthe current Player's turn in that location.\n\n");
    print(board);
    int j=0,cnt=9,turn;
    while (j<cnt && winner==false)
    {
        scanf("%d",&turn);
        if(board[turn/3][turn%3-1]!='O' && board[turn/3][turn%3-1]!='X')
            board[turn/3][turn%3-1] = (j%2==0)?'O':'X';
        else
        {
            printf("Illegal move\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        print(board);
        j++;
        winner = winnerCheck(board,'O') || winnerCheck(board,'X');
    }
    if(!winner)
        printf("Stalemate!\n");
}
int playGame()
{
    char scanned[10];
    printf("Do you wish to play tick-tack-toe?\n");
    scanf("%s", scanned);
    if(strcasecmp(scanned,"yes")==0)
        startGame();
    else
    {
        if (strcmp(scanned,"no")==0 || strcmp(scanned,"nah")==0 || strcmp(scanned,"naw")==0)
            printf("That's too bad!\nThis program will now end.");
        else
            printf("Not valid input!\nThis program will now end.");
        return 1;
    }
}
int main()
{
    playGame();
    return 0;
}
```

The changes are listed out:

- One of the reasons to tackle the increasing length of your code was board printing  repetition of code. This is handled by the usage of `print(char board[][3])` function
- Your code would not stop in case one of the winners has won; and at the end of the program, in case none of the users win, the program simply terminates. The `winnerCheck(char board[][3], char check)` takes in the board configuration and checks for the first/second user's winning condition. And after detecting a successful triumph, terminates after a notification to the players.
- In case a user tries to make an illegal move at a location already occupied, the line of code : `if(board[turn/3][turn%3-1]!='O' && board[turn/3][turn%3-1]!='X')` takes care of this situation.
- In case there is no winner, the program checks for the `winner` variable and notifies the players.
- The `else` part of code in the `playgame()` function has repeated `return 1;` statements. The revised working code addresses the issue.
- The turn array is not necessary and rather a character turn variable is used for taking in the user inputs. One may check the validity of the user's input as well since the number should be in `[1-9]` range. The board coordinates to be set can be decided using `(turn/3,turn%3-1)` rather than a set of `if` statements.
- Something you may try: The user may enter a word longer than 3 characters; thus use a character array of longer than 3 length, say 10 charaters. But the user may use a 11 character word. Hence, as a solution, one may try to address this by specifying a boolean choice of `[0/1]` in the terminal and prompt the user to enter again if the choice is incorrect, since it may be possible that the user enters `affirmative` or `negation` words in different language or dialect.

Comment: Thank you, but as I said "I still wish to add features." I just wanted some ideas on how to minimize the lines code used given what I already had.

Comment: @SuperGoA Yes, indeed. It is now 70 lines of code(good reduction from the previous 250 lines of code).

Comment: I think `print` is a really bad naming of a very specific function. It sound like a very general output function from the standard library. I'd call it something like `printboard` to remove ambiguity.

Comment: @jacwah I agree.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is to use a "`switch`/`case`" expression. Here's how it works:

```
switch (expression that evaluates to int) {
    case 1:
    {
        // code to be executed if the expression evaluates to 1
        break;
    }
    // add as many cases as needed
    default:
    {
         // this is the "else" case.
         break;
    }
}
```

This way, you won't need to write statements such as these:

```
if (turn[j] == 1)
{
      // code
}
```

You can replace them with this:

```
switch(turn[j]) {
    case 1:
    {
        // code
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        // more code
        break;
    }
    default
    {
        // it equals neither 1 nor 2
        break;
    }
}
```

In addition, instead of explicitly stating conditions for "if"s can only run if something is 0, you can simply remove the "`==0`" and put a binary "not" operator in front of the condition. (0 is binary for "false")

When you start the game, you can remove all of the "if" statements within what should be `if (!(j%2))` and replace it with this:

```
board[(turn[j] - 1) / 3][(turn[j] - 1) % 3] = '0'
printf("\n\n %c | %c | %c\n-----------\n %c | %c | %c\n-----------\n %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2], board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2], board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
```

Comment: Why will the code better if OP puts lots of thing on one line, without breaking it off. I'd consider this bad practice, since you reduce readability a lot.

Comment: @jacwah it reduces the number of lines and the size of the code by a couple bytes.

Comment: Yes, but how is that beneficial? OP could omit all whitespace from they're code and reduce the size by ~0.5 KB, but the program would be incomprehensible. That's 0.00000005% of the capacity of my HDD. If space is a concern - use compression software like `gzip`. The easier code is to read, the easier it is to find bugs in it and to maintain it. This should be the aim of reviews. For writing as short code as possible there's [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Comment: @jacwah It also reduces a bit of work for the processor; it doesn't have to process a whole bunch of `print(f)` statements.

Comment: That's potentially true, and the reason I also mentioned breaking the line off.

Comment: @jacwah I thought you meant keeping all of the `printf` statements. Breaking it off would be a good idea. That's up to the OP whether or not they want to do that.